# Why does crossfilter.js not filter other view after brushing?

Tags: d3.js, crossfilter

I am brushing a histogram using `d3.js`, and am using `crossfilter.js` for filtering the views:

```
var chart = scatterPlot()
    .width(350)
    .height(350)
    .x(function (d) { return d.key[0] })
    .y(function (d) { return d.key[1] });

d3.csv("data.csv", function (data) {// data in form of x,y,z,x1,y1

        var csData = crossfilter(data);

        // scatterplot data
        csData.dimScatter = csData.dimension(function (d) {
            return [parseFloat(d.x1), parseFloat(d.y1)];
        });

        csData.byScatter = csData.dimScatter.group();

        csData.dimHistogram = csData.dimension(function (d) {
            return Math.floor(parseFloat(d.z) * 10) / 10;
        });

        csData.byHistogram = csData.dimHistogram.group();

        histogram1.onBrushed(function (selected) {
            csData.dimHistogram.filter(selected);
            update();
        });

        function update() {       
            d3.select("#scatterplot")
                .datum(csData.byScatter.all())
                .call(chart);

            d3.select("#histogram")
                .datum(csData.byHistogram.all())
                .call(histogram1);
        }    
        update();
    });
```

Even though the histogram gets brushed(`selected` shows the data that I brush), the data does not get filtered. Why is that occurring ?
[image: Brush]

Edit 1 - added [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kenkaneki/yquuhs3z/3/)

Edit 2 - code for `chart`:

```
function scatterPlot() {

        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
            width = 350,
            height = 350,
            innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right,
            innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            xValue = function(d) { return d[0]; },
            yValue = function(d) { return d[1]; },
            xScale = d3.scaleLinear(),
            yScale = d3.scaleLinear();

        function chart(selection) {
            selection.each(function (data) {

                // Select the svg element, if it exists.
                var svg = d3.select(this).selectAll("svg").data([data]);

                // Otherwise, create the skeletal chart.
                var svgEnter = svg.enter().append("svg");
                var gEnter = svgEnter.append("g");
                gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "x axis");
                gEnter.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");

                // Update the outer dimensions.
                svg.merge(svgEnter).attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);

                // Update the inner dimensions.
                var g = svg.merge(svgEnter).select("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


                xScale.rangeRound([0, innerWidth])
                //d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.x1; })
                    .domain([-1.5, 1.5]);
                yScale.rangeRound([innerHeight, 0])
                    .domain([-1.5, 1.5]);

                g.select(".x.axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + innerHeight + ")")
                    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));

                g.select(".y.axis")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale).ticks(10))
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Frequency");

                var points = g.selectAll(".point")
                    .data(function (d) { return d; });

                points.enter().append("circle")
                    .attr("class", "point")
                    .merge(points)
                    .attr("cx", X)
                    .attr("cy", Y)
                    .attr("r", 2.5);

                points.exit().remove();
            });

        }

        // The x-accessor for the path generator; xScale ∘ xValue.
        function X(d) {
            return xScale(xValue(d));
        }

        // The y-accessor for the path generator; yScale ∘ yValue.
        function Y(d) {
            return yScale(yValue(d));
        }

        chart.margin = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return margin;
            margin = _;
            return chart;
        };

        chart.width = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return width;
            width = _;
            return chart;
        };

        chart.height = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return height;
            height = _;
            return chart;
        };

        chart.x = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return xValue;
            xValue = _;
            return chart;
        };

        chart.y = function(_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return yValue;
            yValue = _;
            return chart;
        };

        return chart;
    }
```

Edit 3: [Running Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kenkaneki/yquuhs3z/9/)

Comment: Please share the code of `chart`. A working example would be preferable. The Crossfilter code looks alright to me at first glance.

Comment: @EthanJewett I linked a JSFiddle to the question. The script needs a csv file as input, but I have written comments in the script as to what type of values the csv file needs

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Crossfilter questions that are tagged “JavaScript” have an annoying tendency to collect these drive-by downvotes. You might want to remove that tag. Would also be best to include all the relevant code in the actual question, as “them’s the rules”. I’ll try to take a look at the fiddle soon regardless.

Comment: @EthanJewett thanks, edited the question.

Comment: I don't see anything immediately wrong with the code you shared either. The JSFiddle is not working for me though. Any chance you could make sure that is running?

Comment: @EthanJewett I updated the fiddle. You can run it now

Comment: @EthanJewett did you check the updated fiddle? If you run the script, you'll see that the values in the scatterplot won't get filtered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated fiddle that is working: https://jsfiddle.net/yquuhs3z/15/

More or less, you want to take a look at the data returned by `csData.byScatter.all()`. Notably, groups that have no records in them don't go away, they just end up with a value of `0`, so you need to filter out groups you don't want based on their value before charting them. The means replacing

```
d3.select("#scatterplot")
                .datum(csData.byScatter.all())
```

with

```
d3.select("#scatterplot")
                .datum(csData.byScatter.all().filter(d => d.value !== 0))
```

The example also includes some logging using `console.log` that may help you work this kind of thing out in the future, though many people prefer using the Javascript debugger for this kind of thing.